# Конфликт слайдера

Tags: jquery

Написал простенький слайдер и обнаружил ошибку.
Если слайдер один на странице - то всё ок.
Если слайдеров два - то они переключают изображение через одно.

Самое странное то, что управление сделано под текущий блок, т.е. такого конфликта не должно быть, ну или я где-то профукал момент.

Вот код самого слайдера:

```js
Slider();

function Slider() {
  $('.slider-block').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.slider-item').eq(0).addClass('slider-active');
  });

  $('.slider-block .slider-button').on('click', function() {
    var sliderParent = $(this).closest('.slider-block'),
      buttonPrev = $(this).hasClass('slider-prev'),
      buttonNext = $(this).hasClass('slider-next'),
      slideBlock = sliderParent.find('.slider-item'),
      slideActive = sliderParent.find('.slider-active'),
      slideLen = slideBlock.length,
      slideActiveIndex = slideActive.index(),
      slidePrev = (slideActiveIndex - 1),
      slideNext = (slideActiveIndex + 1);
    slideBlock.removeClass('slider-active');

    if (buttonPrev) {
      slideBlock.eq(slidePrev).addClass('slider-active');
    }

    if (buttonNext) {
      if (slideNext == slideLen) var slideNext = 0;
      slideBlock.eq(slideNext).addClass('slider-active');
    }
    var sliderLenThis = sliderParent.find('.slider-active').index();
    sliderParent.find('.slider-len-this').text(sliderLenThis + 1);
  });
}
```

```css
.slider-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider-block .slider-head {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #8e9aa9;
}

.slider-block .slider-head .slider-len,
.slider-block .slider-head .slider-button {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
}

.slider-block .slider-head .slider-len {
  width: calc(100% - 70px);
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: right;
}

.slider-block .slider-head .slider-button {
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-block .slider-head .slider-button i {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: auto;
}

.slider-block .slider-head .slider-button:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #8e9aa9;
}

.slider-block .slider-content {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.slider-block .slider-content-wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider-block .slider-content-wrap .slider-item {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider-block .slider-content-wrap .slider-item.slider-active {
  display: block;
}

.slider-block .slider-content-wrap .slider-item img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider-block .slider-head .slider-button i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider-block">
  <div class="slider-head">
    <div class="slider-len o-ns">
      <span class="slider-len-this">1</span>
      <span>/</span>
      <span class="slider-len-max">4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-button slider-prev o-ns o-am">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-left">&#9668;</i>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-button slider-next o-ns o-am">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-right">&#9658;</i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-content">
    <div class="slider-content-wrap">
      <div class="slider-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Slide 1" />
      </div>
      <div class="slider-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Slide 2" />
      </div>
      <div class="slider-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Slide 3" />
      </div>
      <div class="slider-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Slide 4" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Слайдеров несколько - [ссылка](https://cbipok2513.tumblr.com)
Слайдер один - [ссылка](https://cbipok2513.tumblr.com/post/178849670203)

Comment: @НикитаФаст, если перейти по ссылке "Слайдеров несколько", то там первый слайдер перелистывается через одну фотку.

Comment: я здесь не разберусь - извените

Comment: а если сделать слайдер на css , ммм ? он конечно не будет управляемым но зато без глюков

Comment: @НикитаФаст, не хочу перепиливать под CSS)

Comment: да там собственно делать наверно 20 минут ...не сложная задача

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Всегда проверяйте где находится скрипт.**

Скрипт находился рядом с каждым слайдером => "включался" столько же раз, сколько и слайдеров на странице.